# .net interop System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.InternalWrapIUnknownWithComObject dead lock in some occasions

Tags: c#, com-interop, rcw

we are experiencing a deadlock when trying to use a RCW in C# code which is wrapping a C++ Com object.
It works most of the time, but now and then we have a deadlock where the main thread stops at :

```
Child SP       IP Call Site
0019ad34 75002b3c [GCFrame: 0019ad34] 
0019ad50 75002b3c [HelperMethodFrame: 0019ad50] System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.InternalWrapIUnknownWithComObject(IntPtr)
0019adcc 170de1d5 .ReadAppParameter(IDispatch*)
0019adf0 170ddd4a DomainBoundILStubClass.IL_STUB_ReversePInvoke(Int32)
```

We've tried to debug it, but it's really hard. Somehow, something is blocking the the thread that makes the communication between managed and native but I can't see which.

Calling !eestack gives me the following information, but I can't see what is causing the dead lock.
This thread is calling CleanupWrappersInCurrentCtxThread which is somehow suspicious, but I don't have the details on how this all internally works:

```
    Thread   0
    Current frame: win32u!NtUserPeekMessage+0xc
    ChildEBP RetAddr  Caller, Callee
    0019a2bc 7530fb5e user32!_PeekMessage+0x2e, calling win32u!NtUserPeekMessage
    0019a2f8 75305a58 user32!DispatchMessageWorker+0x328, calling win32u!NtUserDispatchMessage
    0019a310 752f6b7c user32!PeekMessageA+0x19c, calling user32!_PeekMessage
    0019a34c 698040b8 msvbvm60!VBDllUnRegisterServer+0x94c5
    0019a3a0 763182a9 combase!CCliModalLoop::HandlePendingMessage+0xe2
    0019a3c8 75002b4c win32u!NtUserCallOneParam+0xc
    0019a3cc 75311182 user32!GetQueueStatus+0x52, calling win32u!NtUserCallOneParam
    0019a3e0 76318149 combase!CCliModalLoop::HandleWakeForMsg+0x126, calling combase!CCliModalLoop::HandlePendingMessage
    0019a3f8 7631838e combase!CCliModalLoop::MyPeekMessage+0x43, calling combase!__SEH_epilog4
    0019a3fc 76318328 combase!CCliModalLoop::PeekRPCAndDDEMessage+0x31, calling combase!CCliModalLoop::MyPeekMessage
    0019a408 753112cd user32!MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x4d, calling user32!RealMsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx
    0019a440 7629de9a combase!CCliModalLoop::BlockFn+0x234, calling combase!CCliModalLoop::HandleWakeForMsg
    0019a474 76321094 combase!ClassicSTAThreadWaitForHandles+0xb4, calling combase!CCliModalLoop::BlockFn
    0019a534 762f1339 combase!CoWaitForMultipleHandles+0x79, calling combase!ClassicSTAThreadWaitForHandles
    0019a560 737eb78e clr!MsgWaitHelper+0x64, calling combase!CoWaitForMultipleHandles
    0019a5b4 737eb71e clr!Thread::DoAppropriateWaitWorker+0x1d8, calling clr!MsgWaitHelper
    0019a638 7393ce6e clr!Thread::DoAppropriateWait+0x64, calling clr!Thread::DoAppropriateWaitWorker
    0019a6a4 738b310e clr!Thread::JoinEx+0xc5, calling clr!Thread::DoAppropriateWait
    0019a6f4 7394a3a6 clr!RCWCleanupList::CleanupWrappersInCurrentCtxThread+0x133, calling clr!Thread::JoinEx
    0019a718 737daee3 clr!SyncBlock::GetInteropInfo+0x38, calling ntdll!RtlInterlockedPopEntrySList
    0019a71c 737a37bb clr!SyncBlock::GetInteropInfo+0xbd, calling clr!_EH_epilog3
    0019a748 737e5091 clr!RCW::Initialize+0x259, calling clr!RCWCleanupList::CleanupWrappersInCurrentCtxThread
    0019a794 75315d0b user32!_InternalCallWinProc+0x2b
0019a7d4 75306830 user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+0x3d0, calling user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+0x62e
0019a828 13433195 *** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for ociliba.dll
ociliba!OCI_ErrorGet+0x55, calling *** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for oci.dll
oci!OCIThreadKeyGet
0019a844 13446788 ociliba!OCI_MutexRelease+0x78, calling oci!OCIThreadMutexRelease
0019a85c 13466059 ociliba!OCI_StringDuplicateFromOracleString+0xc9, calling ociliba!memcpy
0019a878 1341f355 ociliba!OCI_ColumnDescribe+0xa15, calling oci!OCIDescriptorFree
0019a88c 1341f376 ociliba!OCI_ColumnDescribe+0xa36, calling ociliba!__security_check_cookie
0019a8c0 7717ae60 ntdll!RtlFreeHeap+0x1e0, calling ntdll!RtlpHpStackLoggingEnabled
0019a908 747e5fcb ucrtbase!_free_base+0x1b, calling ntdll!RtlFreeHeap
0019a91c 747e5f98 ucrtbase!free+0x18, calling ucrtbase!_free_base
0019a92c 601fa425 *** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for NC3001_28.dll
NC3001_28!operator delete+0xb, calling ucrtbase!free
0019a938 60114bb0 NC3001_28!std::_Deallocate<8,0>+0x50, calling NC3001_28!operator delete
0019a958 6015df27 NC3001_28!std::_Tgt_state_t<std::_String_const_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char> > > >::~_Tgt_state_t<std::_String_const_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char> > > >+0x87, calling NC3001_28!std::_Deallocate<8,0>
0019a980 60162c3d NC3001_28!std::_Matcher<std::_String_const_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char> > >,char,std::regex_traits<char>,std::_String_const_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char> > > >::_Do_if+0x14d, calling NC3001_28!std::_Tgt_state_t<std::_String_const_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char> > > >::~_Tgt_state_t<std::_String_const_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char> > > >
0019a9a8 7717ae60 ntdll!RtlFreeHeap+0x1e0, calling ntdll!RtlpHpStackLoggingEnabled
0019a9f0 747e5fcb ucrtbase!_free_base+0x1b, calling ntdll!RtlFreeHeap
0019aa04 747e5f98 ucrtbase!free+0x18, calling ucrtbase!_free_base
0019aa14 601fa425 NC3001_28!operator delete+0xb, calling ucrtbase!free
0019aa20 60114bb0 NC3001_28!std::_Deallocate<8,0>+0x50, calling NC3001_28!operator delete
0019aa40 6015df27 NC3001_28!std::_Tgt_state_t<std::_String_const_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char> > > >::~_Tgt_state_t<std::_String_const_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char> > > >+0x87, calling NC3001_28!std::_Deallocate<8,0>
0019aa68 6015b506 NC3001_28!std::_Regex_search2<std::_String_const_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char> > >,std::allocator<std::sub_match<std::_String_const_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char> > > > >,char,std::regex_traits<char>,std::_String_const_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char> > > >+0x1b6, calling NC3001_28!std::_Tgt_state_t<std::_String_const_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char> > > >::~_Tgt_state_t<std::_String_const_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char> > > >
0019aa70 7717ae60 ntdll!RtlFreeHeap+0x1e0, calling ntdll!RtlpHpStackLoggingEnabled
0019aa80 7717ae60 ntdll!RtlFreeHeap+0x1e0, calling ntdll!RtlpHpStackLoggingEnabled
0019aa90 7717ae60 ntdll!RtlFreeHeap+0x1e0, calling ntdll!RtlpHpStackLoggingEnabled
0019aad4 76eedcbe KERNELBASE!wil_details_ModifyFeatureData+0x2d, calling KERNELBASE!wil_details_SetPropertyFlagCallback
0019ab50 7717d35e ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap+0x3e, calling ntdll!RtlpAllocateHeapInternal
0019ab58 7717d35e ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap+0x3e, calling ntdll!RtlpAllocateHeapInternal
0019ab70 737a2788 clr!EEHeapAlloc+0x2c, calling ntdll!RtlAllocateHeap
0019ab88 737a27ca clr!EEHeapAllocInProcessHeap+0x5b, calling clr!EEHeapAlloc
0019ab94 737a2767 clr!ClrAllocInProcessHeap+0x23
0019abb8 737e514e clr!RCW::CreateRCWInternal+0xdc, calling clr!RCW::Initialize
```

Finalizer looks good:

```
Thread   2
Current frame: ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc
ChildEBP RetAddr  Caller, Callee
050cfb78 76ee9d13 KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x133, calling ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects
050cfbd0 76ee8409 KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0x99, calling ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject
050cfc28 7394821e clr!RCW::EnterContext+0x3a, calling clr!CtxEntry::EnterContext
050cfc44 737a1580 clr!CLREventWaitHelper2+0x33, calling KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObjectEx
050cfc50 737a159d clr!CLREventWaitHelper2+0x4e, calling clr!_EH_epilog3
050cfc70 737a159d clr!CLREventWaitHelper2+0x4e, calling clr!_EH_epilog3
```

The COM object is used to get a Oracle DB handle and the select is done on C#. We can see that oracle is involved but still we are out of ideas on how to check who is really blocking.

If someone have any idea on how I can proceed or know how RCW internally works and what could cause a deadlock I would be thankful.

Right now, we spawn a thread that calls the RCW and it seems to work, but this deadlock should actually not happen.

** Edit 02.10.21 **
This is how my workaround looks like:

```
void ParameterReaderHelper::ReadAppParameter(Object^ obj)
{
    auto lp = (IntPtr)obj;
    MyInterface^ myComInterface = nullptr;
    try
    {
        System::Diagnostics::Debug::WriteLine(
                        "ThreadState: {0},
                        ApartmentState: {1}",
                        Threading::Thread::CurrentThread->ThreadState,
                        Threading::Thread::CurrentThread->GetApartmentState());

        myComInterface = (MyInterface^)EnterpriseServicesHelper::WrapIUnknownWithComObject(lp);
        System::Diagnostics::Debug::WriteLine("myComInterface:" + myComInterface->GetHashCode());
        
        // do something with myComInterface
    }
    finally
    {
        // ...
    }

}
```

And I call it using this... not really proud of it though.

```
bool ReadAppParameter(IDispatch* lp)
{
    const int Delay = 100;
    const int OneMinute = 60 * 1000 / Delay;

    System::Diagnostics::Debug::WriteLine(
        "ThreadState: {0},
        ApartmentState: {1}",
        Threading::Thread::CurrentThread->ThreadState,
        Threading::Thread::CurrentThread->GetApartmentState());

    auto obj = IntPtr(lp);
    auto goh = gcnew ParameterReaderHelper();
    Threading::Tasks::Task^ myTask = Threading::Tasks::Task::Factory->StartNew((Action<Object^>^)(gcnew Action<Object^>(goh, &ParameterReaderHelper::ReadAppParameter)), obj);

    int count = 0;

    while (!goh->IsFinished() && count < OneMinute )
    {
        Threading::Thread::Sleep(Delay);
        count++;
    }

    if (count >= OneMinute)
    {
        throw gcnew System::InvalidOperationException("blabla");
    }

    return true;
}
```

But this solves the blocking for now.
If I try to wait on the task. It blocks forever.

Rings any bells?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this [Github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/12536) help shed any light on your issue?

Comment: You have a msvbvm60!VBDllUnRegisterServer (VB/VBA unregister COM object why?) and a message loop in the stack (STA thread probably?). Is there a VB object somewhere? how is the threading state of all this?

Comment: @SimonMourier yes,  there is a VB Application that is hosting C++, C# and other things. Everything through COM. This problem happens however also when the main application (Plugin Host) in in C++.  All COM Objects we use are STA. They do not support MTA. Perhaps interop makes them accessible from many threads.

Comment: Do you create and use multiple threads ? It's fairly possible to create locks with STAs . Google "sta thread deadlock" to have a glimpse

Comment: Right. But as far as I understand how it works, the thread that communicates with the COM objects is always the same. The only reason I can see is that something is blocking it. But in windbg I can't see  it. I will add the way I've got it working on the original question. Perhaps this can help find the problem.